# upgrading google chrome on centos 6.0 using yum not working

Tags: google-chrome, centos, yum, centos-6

I tried upgrading my chrome 26.x by going to the "about google chrome" page -- but unlike my windows chrome, the linux chrome(centos 6.0) v 26.x did not offer to upgrade to the latest version.

I downloaded the latest linux chrome for fedora x86_64 bit and then tried to install it -- however, that command failed saying that my libstdc++ needed upgrading. So, I then tried to upgrade my libstdc++ to the new version; however, "yum install" didn't comply. What gives ?

```
foo@bar Downloads]# rpm -ivh ./google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm
    error: Failed dependencies:
        libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit) is needed by google-chrome-stable-28.0.1500.95-213514.x86_64

foo@bar Downloads]# yum install libstdc++.so.6
    Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
    Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
     * base: mirror.vietoss.com
     * epel: ftp.jaist.ac.jp
     * extras: mirrors.ispros.com.bd
     * updates: mirror.vietoss.com
    Setting up Install Process
    Package libstdc++-4.4.7-3.el6.i686 already installed and latest version
    Nothing to do
foo@bar Downloads]#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Chrome version 28, RHEL/CentOS 6 is no longer supported. You'll have to use Chromium instead. I used to recommend the howto [at this page](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2013/install-chromium-on-centos-red-hat-rhel/), which includes links to a Chromium repository for RHEL as well as instructions for using Chrome's Pepper Flash and PDF Viewer in Chromium, but the PDF viewer stopped working because it too required a newer glibc than RHEL/CentOS had. [Richard Lloyd's Chrome installer](http://chrome.richardlloyd.org.uk/) is now the best option as of early 2014.

Answer (score 2):

1. Linux users maintain packages through their *package managers* and *repositories* not *download websites*, thus auto-updaters don't fit in well with the modular package ecosystem.
2. CentOS 6.0 is from **2011**, please upgrade to the latest release (6.4). The [official wiki guide](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/MigrationGuide) or [using the package manager](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2011/upgrade-centos-6/).
3. `libstdc++.so.6` is a shared object **file** not a package. Surprised `yum` was able to deduce you meant the `libstdc++` package - which as the output states, the installed version is the most recent version available in the repositories you have enabled for CentOS 6.0.
4. The reason more recent versions of **Google Chrome** require a newer libstdc++.so than the one you have (you can check which version you have using `readlink -e /usr/lib/libstdc++.so`) is that it was *"compiled against"* it (or rather *linked* with it). Chrome's source code is **not open** thus you are unable attempt to recompile it for your system.
5. The open-source **Chromium** browser, which *Google Chrome* is based on, which lacks some *proprietary functionality* but is a usable alternative is something can choose to compile for your system.

As stated, if you want the latest version without too much trouble you really need to upgrade your OS.

Comment: thanks for your answer <br>. I chose to accept polpo's answer given that it gives me a way to install the latest chromium on centos 6.0. I have other software installed on my box that I'm afraid of losing if I upgrade centos to 6.4.

Answer (score 0):

I installed Chrome 31 successfully on CentOS 6 with the script provided on this [page](http://chrome.richardlloyd.org.uk).